# (ATA PIO) Garbage reads from port

Tags: x86, operating-system, bootloader, protected-mode, ata

I have been trying to write a ATA PIO driver to load files from protected mode, but it would seem that all the data I recieve from the port is garbage (`0xffff`).

This is my first time writing a PIO driver so Iam not really sure what I'm doing is correct. I have been following the link from OsDev to get 28 bit PIO working. (https://wiki.osdev.org/ATA_PIO_Mode#28_bit_PIO)

Here is the code snippet which tries to load the first sector using PIO reads.

```
extern void ata_disk_wait();
extern void ata_drq_wait();

void read_sector(uint32_t sector)
{
    ata_disk_wait(); // wait BSY to 0 and RDY to 1
    outb(0x1F6, sector >> 24 | 0xE0);// Master drive
    outb(0x1F2, 1); // Read one sector
    outb(0x1F3, sector);
    outb(0x1F4, sector >> 8);
    outb(0x1F5, sector >> 16);
    // Make a read call
    outb(0x1F7, 0x20);
    // transfere
}

void read_kernel(uint32_t address, uint32_t sector)
{
    read_sector(sector);
    ata_disk_wait();
    ata_drq_wait();// wait DRQ to 1
    // copy to address
    // insw(0x1F0, (uint32_t)address, 512/2);
}

void
boot_main()
{
    byte *address = (byte *)0x10000; // Save kernel at address
    read_kernel((uint32_t)address, 1);
}
```

and from my asm I call this like so:

```
mov     sp, 07c00h
call    boot_main

;; get data from port
mov     dx, 01F0h
xor     eax, eax
in      al, dx
mov     [010000h], al
```

Here are the disk_wait and drq_wait functions:

```
    global ata_drq_wait
ata_drq_wait:
    pusha
    xor al, al
    mov dx, 01F7h
.loop:   
    in  al, dx
    test al, 008h
    jz .loop
.end:
    popa
    ret


    global ata_disk_wait
ata_disk_wait:
    pusha
    xor ax, ax
    mov dx, 01F7h
.loop:
    in  al, dx
    and al, 0C0h
    cmp al, 040h
    jne .loop
.end:
    popa
    ret
```

But all the data which I receive seems to be `0xffff`.

I have checked the boot_disk value in my boot loader. and the value of dl is `080h` so qemu does boot from hard disk.

Comment: Be careful if inteerupts are enabled, the IRQ handler may steal your data.

Comment: @MargaretBloom That was it !!!! After switching to protected mode I forgot to clear interrupts. Thanks. If you want to submit it as an answer for anyone with the same problem, I shall accept it

Comment: An answer is deserved, I remember going crazy too (back then) for this IRQ thing. But why don't you write it yourself instead? :) You surely can give a more contextual, and longer, answer :)